# Can not get a NSURL from UITextField in Xcode

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield, nsurl

I am having problems when working with nsurl's because i have made app that can download and it doe this just fine and works with the code bellow. However i want the user to type the url into a NSTextField and then allow the same function to work.

```
NSURL *youTubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoHf5ZzARtM"];
```

**Here is the code that does not work:**

```
NSURL *youTubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:texturl.text];

////texturl is the name of the outlet for my uitextfield.
```

Edit

2013-06-28 21:17:59.251 youtube video link[307:14003] -[UITextField stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x868bb80
2013-06-28 21:17:59.254 youtube video link[307:14003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x868bb80'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2326012 0x13b1e7e 0x23b14bd 0x2315bbc 0x231594e 0x2b96 0x28dd 0x13c5705 0x5222c0 0x522258 0x5e3021 0x5e357f 0x5e26e8 0x551cef 0x551f02 0x52fd4a 0x521698 0x1bc8df9 0x1bc8ad0 0x229bbf5 0x229b962 0x22ccbb6 0x22cbf44 0x22cbe1b 0x1bc77e3 0x1bc7668 0x51effc 0x26a2 0x25d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: log the text of the UITextField to see if (1) your textField is connected correctly to the outlet (2) the entered text is a valid url --> `NSLog(@"Text: \"%@\"", texturl.text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However i want the user to type the url into a NSTextField and then
>   allow the same function to work.

`NSTextField` ???

Then you need to use:

```
NSURL *youTubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[texturl stringValue]];
```

For `UITextField`, you have `text`, not for `NSTextField`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response

Comment: vaidya i have tried your code and it is displaying a error and the app crashes check out he edit to see the error

Comment: @user2425997 - you have to change the type of texturl to NSTextField. Yours is set to UITexField.

Comment: @katzenhut nope. The exception clearly indicates that his object is a UITextField. Don't use stringValue, use `.text`

Comment: I have tried .text but nothing send to happen the app does not function correctly

Comment: I typed the question quickly but it was ment to uitextfield where it sayed nstextfield

Comment: @MatthiasBauch - of course it does. so theres 2 ways to solve it: use a NSTextfield and -stringValue, or use a UITextField and -text. I missed the cocoa-touch-tag below the question and figured he was on OSX. My bad...